# Mini-Jack headphone extension without cutting sound

Tags: audio, headphones

On my digital piano the headphone jack is at the back which is impractical. Is there any jack device that can be plugged without cutting the sound, for example with a switch, so I can pull an extension to a more convenient place to plug headphones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound switches off when you insert a plug into the headphones socket, due to switches built into the socket. This is what that looks like:

[image]

The plug pushes those contacts apart. The only way to prevent that would be a custom plug that is designed to work with the specific socket design in your keyboard. Not an easy fix.

If the keyboard has line outputs, you could connect a headphones amplifier to them and use that instead.